# Rails - ActiveResource returning hash instead of an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

I've got the following code

```
u = Client.get(:show_by_username, :username => username.downcase)
```

When a valid user is returned, they seem to be getting returned as a hash instead of an object that I can call methods on

e.g. I have to access values like

```
u['id']
```

instead of

```
u.id
```

How can I get it to return it as an object?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the docs for the  [ActiveResource 'get' method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/CustomMethods.html#method-c-get), it does not convert them into ActiveResource::Base instances. As it says, you need to use the `find` method instead:

```
u = Client.find(:all, :from => :show_by_username, :params => { :username => username.downcase })
```